# Dropdown contendo imagem à direita

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

Estou utilizando o Bootstrap para fazer uma barra no topo da página, e estou com um problema:

O que preciso, é ao abrir o dropdown, ter uma lista de opções, e uma imagem ao lado que tenha sempre o mesmo tamanho da lista, conforme imagem abaixo.

Consegui isto setando um height e width fixos na imagem, porém a lista pode crescer e não posso ficar alterando na mão.

Uma solução que funcionaria é colocar uma div envolvendo a lista e a imagem, e setar o tamanho da imagem para 100%, porém ao fazer isso, o dropdown não é mais ativado (creio que eu acabo quebrando a estrutura que o bootstrap utiliza para ativar o dropdown).

Como posso atingir esta solução?

Obrigado!

[image: estrutura]

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav top-elements">
                <li id="dropdown-produtos" class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle text-uppercase top-text" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Nossos Produtos<span class="caret top-caret"></span></a>
<!-- a div ia aqui --> <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-produtos">
                        <li class="dropdown-item-active">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item-description">texto1</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu img-dropdown">
                                 <img src="assets/img.png"> 
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-item-description">texto2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item-description">texto3</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item-description">texto4</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item"><a href="#" class="dropdown-item-description">texto5</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Você disse que a lista pode aumentar. Como ficaria se a imagem não for do tamanho da lista? Ficaria com o restante em branco?

Comment: @Randrade o ideal é que a imagem se adeque sempre ao tamanho da lista, herdando a altura da mesma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Cansei de ver essa pergunta sem resposta... então vai ai uma opção.</sup>

A ideia é ter no `dropdown` duas listas, uma com o Menu, e outra apenas com a imagem, usandp `display:flex` no *container* desse Menu vc vai ter a lista de itens de um lado e a imagem a esquerda, essa imagem na verdade é um `background-image` e sempre vai ocupar a totalidade da altura do menu, não importa quantos itens tenham dentro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para entender melhor veja o código referente a imagem acima.

**OBS:** Exiba em "Página toda" para ter um melhor resultado, apesar de que tb funciona bem no Menu mobile.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<style>
  .dropdown.open .dropdown-menu.teste {
    display: flex;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .dropdown.open .dropdown-menu li ul {
    padding: 5px 0;
    margin: 2px 0 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
    list-style: none;
  }
  .dropdown.open .dropdown-menu li ul li a{
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    color: #333;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  .dropdown.open .dropdown-menu.teste .imagem {
    width: 100px;
    background-image: url(https://placecage.com/100/100);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
  .dropdown.open .dropdown-menu.teste .imagem.murray {
    background-image: url(https://fillmurray.com/100/100);
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
  
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          </div>
      
          <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu teste">
                  <li>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="imagem"></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 2<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu teste">
                  <li>
                    <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                      <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                      <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="imagem murray"></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="navbar-form navbar-left">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 2<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```